# Remote Safari driver for Safari 11 cannot click element

Tags: selenium-grid, safaridriver

I am using Selenium grid jar on a mac machine.

When:

1. the test is started
2. Safari browser is opened
3. the target web page is navigated to
4. `findElement()` is completed successfully

**but** on attempted click or getting element displayed or visible state, there is

> "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.".

There was nothing in the node console log when the error occurred.
I am only using the `"browserName", "safari"` desired capability.

I have been searching for version dependencies or other capabilities needed, but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Versions:

- Safari 11.1.1,
- Selenium-standalone 3.12.0,
- Selenium.WebDriver 3.12.1